# Problem in installing "dplyr" package due to update of R?

Tags: r

Can you tell me how to update R from CRAN using the RStudio terminal? I've tried doing it manually, but it's not working,I've encountered an error while installing the "dplyr" package. I'm hoping updating through the terminal will fix it. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

[image]

I am facing error in installing libraries because of old version of r, i have installed it manually but it still not fetching modules due to old version of r.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo.  it is "dplyr" and not "deplyr"

Comment: No, "deplyr" is correct. d is for data.frame , plyr as in a set of pliers to manipulate things with. dplyr is a data. frame specific set of tools like plyr .

Comment: Please read again:  there is no package "deplyr" at CRAN.  And there never was.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I am already considering 'dplyr' but i don't know why it showing 'deplyr' in output..

Comment: Unless you're installing a package that misspelled "dplyr" in its dependencies, which is unlikely for it to have made it through any build process, the warning message says "deplyr" because that's the way you misspelled it. We can't know for sure because you haven't included what you did that got you that message

Answer (score 1):

For Windows systems you could use the `installr` package while the `updateR()` function from the `rstudioapi` package is an option for macOS and Linux.

You can find a guide including a step-by-step instruction here: https://r-lang.com/how-to-update-r-using-rstudio/

After having installed the new R-version and having restarted Rstudio it is probably most convenient to update the packages via the RStudio menu (Tools -> Check for package updates -> select all or select desired packages referring to "installed" and "available" columns -> install updates)

Comment: Thanks, for explaining this very well after following your steps it shows that the update requirement is satisfied but whenever i try to install "deplyr" package again occuring same error.